# How do I use app.yaml with Java runtime in App Engine v1.9.18?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I followed [the documentation for using app.yaml with Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml) which claims that this should work and that it will generate `web.xml` and `appengine-web.xml` automatically. However, it doesn't seem to work and it doesn't mention which tool will generate the files.

I first tried a `mvn clean install` which errors out because the `.xml` files are missing:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) on project roger-analytics: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]

I then tried to run the local development server:

```
$ gcloud preview app run app.yaml
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.run) An error occurred while parsing file: [/Users/blixt/src/roger-api/module_analytics/app.yaml]
Unexpected attribute 'servlet' for object of type URLMap.
  in "/Users/blixt/src/roger-api/module_analytics/app.yaml", line 7, column 12
```

(I get the same error from `dev_appserver.py .` by the way)

It appears that `app.yaml` isn't supported after all. Am I missing something, or was support removed without updating the documentation?

Here's my `app.yaml` file, which is intended to run as a module in my Google Cloud App Engine project (along with other modules that have Python and Go runtimes):

```
module: analytics
runtime: java
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /*
  servlet: im.rgr.roger.RogerAnalytics
  login: admin
  secure: always

system_properties:
  java.util.logging.config.file: WEB-INF/logging.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues at play here. I'll describe various facts that group together to create a constellation of SDK edge-case goodness (this information is current as of SDK 1.9.21):

- In order to deploy using the [Java SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads)'s `appcfg.sh`, you'll need to have `app.yaml` inside the `war/WEB-INF/` folder.
- `appcfg.py` complains `Unexpected attribute 'servlet' for object of type URLMap.`.
- `gcloud preview app deploy` uses `appcfg.py` (or the same codebase) and therefore also complains in the same manner

---

So, in conclusion, you'll need to use `appcfg.sh`

Comment: This answer was edited, since I initially thought there were more issues than there are. Using the Java SDK to deploy the Java project is pretty sane, although it would be nice if gcloud knew about this instead of defaulting to appcfg.py. I encourage you to file a [public issue tracker issue for this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/), as a feature request *or* bug report.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I removed the standalone Java SDK (`appcfg.sh`) ages ago after `gcloud` told me to in order to avoid conflicts. We've been using `appengine-maven-plugin` but I'm trying out `gcloud-maven-plugin` (0.9.68.v20150707). Is there an easy way for `gcloud` and `appcfg.sh` to co-exist?

Comment: Someone has now created an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12119), which I've starred.